# How to create a Certificate Signing Request on Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How can we generate a certificate signing request (CSR) on Xamarin platforms.

[CertificateRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest?view=net-5.0) can be used for this in desktop .net however Xamarin/mono platforms do not support it, It throws a PlatformNotSupportedException.

Comment: For a xamarin android or ios app, it different for android and ios, android is simple, we have signing tool and ios is completely different, which one you're looking?

Comment: It's impossible, it only works on desktop.

Comment: @Steven yes the CertificateRequest type doesn't work on Xamarin, but this is far from the only possible way of creating a CSR.

Comment: @logeshpalani98 I'm looking from a cross platform (android and iOS) solution for creating a CSR. (A request for signing a certificate)

Comment: @Steven it is possible see my answer

Comment: @logeshpalani98 It's not completely different for android/ios see my answer using SandCastle

Answer (score 1):

The c# version of SandCastle supports creating Certificate Signing Requests (CSR)

```
 byte[] CreateSigningRequest(string commonName, RSA rsa)
 {
     var name = new X509Name($"C=NZ, O=MyOrg, L=MyLocation, OU=MyOrgUnit, CN={commonName}");
     var keys = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(rsa);
     Pkcs10CertificationRequest csr = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest("SHA256WITHRSA", name, keys.Public, null, keys.Private);
     return csr.GetEncoded();
}
```